# Obtaining the Covariance Matrix for Multivariate Kernel Density Estimates on a Grid of Points

Tags: r, kernel-density

I would like to perform bivariate kernel density estimation in R, obtain predictions on a grid of points, and finally, obtain the covariance matrix for the predictions on this set of points. In particular, I am having trouble with the last step (obtaining the covariance matrix).

I have tried various multivariate kernel density estimation packages in R. The one that gets me closest to what I want is the "locfit" package. It gives me the estimated kernel densities on the grid of points I want, as well as the standard errors. However, I need to know the covariances between these point estimates, which I have not figured out how to obtain.

```r
require('locfit')
X1 = rnorm(1000)
X2 = rnorm(1000)
kernel_density_est = locfit(~ X1 + X2)
test = predict(kernel_density_est, data.frame(X1 = c(0,1), X2 = c(0,1)), se.fit = TRUE)
```

As mentioned above, this gives me the standard errors for the point estimates, but I need the covariance between the point estimates as well.
A
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you tried with `cov(cbind(X1,X2))`?

Comment: Hi @VíctorCortés, thanks for the suggestion. However, that gives me the covariance matrix of X1 and X2, which is not what I want. What I want is the covariance between the estimates of the kernel density at any two points.